# How to add events in javascript fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying this library for the first time
want to set events to my calendar, but instead of doing this:

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',

    titleFormat:{
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'short'  
    },

    events: [{
        title: "February Outing",
        start: "2021-02-19",
        end: "2021-02-21"
    }]
});

calendar.render();
```

I Want to do it like this for some reason

```
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',

        titleFormat:{
            year: 'numeric',
            month: 'short'  
        },
   });


let myEvents = [
    {
        title: "February Outing",
        start: "2021-02-19",
        end: "2021-02-21"
    }
]

calendar.events = myEvents
calendar.render();
```

but it doesn't work
Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Calendar::addEvent`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent). You can set events from your array `myEvents` as follows:

```
myEvents.forEach(event => calendar.addEvent(event))
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use `calendar.addEvent( event [, source ] )`. Kindly refer https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent to get a detailed understanding about this.

They have shared https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent-demo on their documentation as well to give a demo about the issue you raised.